# How do I have the standard errors around regression lines in R with multiple colours in the same plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, colors

I'm using `ggplot` to plot several pieces of data on the same graph. Below, each line is a time point and has different color, which I've manually selected using the `scale_color_manual` function. I'd like to include `standard error` but have the standard error colour match the color of the regression line.

Below I've edited the color of standard error to red by changing the 'fill' in the geom_smooth function. But don't know how to change it so each line and error match.

[image]

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=log10(x), y=y, color=factor(Time)))+ 
  geom_smooth(method="loess", span=2, fill="red") +
  facet_wrap(~Condition)+
  scale_color_manual(name="Time",values=c("red","blue","green"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `fill` aesthetic. This can be done in the `ggplot()` call or in the `geom_smooth` call.

```
data = data.frame(x = runif(60), y = runif(60), 
                  Time = rep(1:3, 20), 
                  Condition = factor(rep(1:2, 30)))

ggplot(data, aes(x=log10(x), y=y, colour=factor(Time), fill =   factor(Time)))+ 
  geom_smooth( method="loess", span=2) +
  facet_wrap(~Condition)+
  scale_color_manual(name="Time", values=c("red","blue","green")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Time", values=c("red","blue","green"))
```

[image]